# Where to set API KEY to deploy on IBM Bluemix Cloud Foundry

Tags: deployment, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, delivery-pipeline

I'm deploying via Delivery Pipeline on IBM Bluemix Cloud Foundry.
On logs I have this message:

> WARNING: Deploying to Cloud Foundry without specifying an API KEY is DEPRECATED. Press the [CONFIGURE] button above to include an API KEY for this job.

What is API KEY and where I have to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API key can be set in the Deploy configuration, around the middle of the panel: 
[image: IBM Cloud Deploy Configuration]

From the drop-down, select 'Add an existing API key' and then paste in a key.

(The key can be created on the command line using `ibmcloud iam api-key-create MyKey -d "this is my API key" --file key_file` if there isn't already one for the user whose identity the deploy should be done under.)